# Deploying a custom static folder under wwwroot

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, webdeploy, microsoft-web-deploy

We have a custom folder under **wwwroot** named **Contents** with some inner folders shaping a structure for organizing later uploadable files, in the publish mode it is not deployed (On local or server)

Here is part of our code which you may be interested about:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
        Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Contents")),
    RequestPath = "/Contents"
});
```

Any suggestions and solutions? Any idea why it is not deployed?

***Update:***

In .csProj we have this:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Contents\H2X\" />
    <Folder Include="ServerContent\H123\" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

We have H2X.publishSettings file,
which is generated by the server and contains some of our credentials.

```
   msdeploySite="213" 
   destinationAppUrl="123" 
   profileName="Default Settings" 
   publishMethod="MSDeploy" userName="123" 
   AllowUntrustedCertificate="True"
```

Is there anything missed?

I was a bit away from development for a while, now my developer seems stuck with it, wanted to help him.

Comment: Check the publish script under the .csproj, not code in the Startup class

Comment: Is there anything in the folder? I've seen visual studio ignore empty folders. If you've created the folder in the VS Solution Explorer, then the folder is 'virtual'...meaning, it doesn't really exist. It can be confusing sometimes.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Added an update, part of the .CSProj and part of the PublishSettings file, are these what you are looking for? Should we add anything to these files?

Comment: @SRQCoder there are just folders and some inner folders, it will be a base structure when we can deal with our code to organize our uploaded images.

Comment: Right, so put something in the folder, not just another empty folder.

Comment: You could also 'create' the appropriate folder at run-time. From memory, I think the 'CreateDirectory' command is used -- Creates the directory if it doesn't exist, does nothing if it does exist. Check to make sure that's the right command.

Comment: Yes, that can be another option and I agree it can be a better option, but at least as an old developer I'm eager to find the issue. That's the method our developer went. About your previous comment, I added an image to each folder and sub-folder, seems on the next deploy also nothing has changed.

Comment: You said that `Contents` lives *inside* `wwwroot` but then your .csproj file shows that it lives at the root of the project. Which one is correct?

Comment: Haha seems you are right, the folder structure he made was a bit wrong. I moved it under wwwroot. now will try to publish.

Comment: It should work if it's underneath `wwwroot`, as that folder gets special treatment and gets copied up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the **Contents** folder inside the **wwwroot** then add

```
<Content Include="wwwroot\**\*" CopyToPublishDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
```

and you no need to configure the **Contents** folder as static file provider in **Startup.cs**, above line will include all sub folders and files inside wwwroot.

And if the **Contents** folder outside of **wwwroot** then add

```
<Content Include="Contents\**\*" CopyToPublishDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
```

and you need to configure the **Contents** folder as static file provider in **Startup.cs**

Comment: there were problems when I used as content, it was dublicate contens, I changed as folder  -> <Folder  Include="wwwroot\**\*" CopyToPublishDirectory="PreserveNewest" />   it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Within the ASP.NET Core hosting environment, there are two properties frequently used in building a physical path to a file or directory.

_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath maps directly to the default wwwroot directory:

_hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath maps one level higher, usually where the startup.cs file is located.

For file uploads directly into a folder located within the wwwroot folder, use WebRootPath in building the path you need.

Comment: And waiting for my developer to check it on the server. will provide feedbacks and continue the discussion if needed.